# My street input field wont work on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my issue,
When ever the form is submitted the street form does not show up in the email I receive. I don't understand why it might not be working I've looked through the php and JS but cant understand why it won't work.
Here i the JS co

```
(function($){    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
     * Contact form ajax
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */

    $('#contact-form').find('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var submit          = $('#contact-form submit');
            var ajaxResponse    = $('#contact-response');

            var name            = $('#contact-form [name="name"]').val();
            var lastname        = $('#contact-form [name="lastname"]').val();
            var email           = $('#contact-form [name="email"]').val();
            var street          = $('#contact-form [name="street"]').val();
            var message         = $('#contact-form [name="message"]').val();


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    email: email,
                    street: street,
                    message: message,
                },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(result) {
                    submit.empty();
                    submit.append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result.sendstatus == 1) {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                        $form.fadeOut(500);
                    } else {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});    })(jQuery);
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php

// Mail settings
$to      = "";
$subject = "PB Enquiry Form - " . $_REQUEST['lastname'];

// You can put here your email
$header = "From:\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

    $content  = "First Name: "      . $_POST["name"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Last Name: " . $_POST["lastname"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Email: "     . $_POST["email"]   . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Street: "    . $_POST["street"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Message: "    . $_POST["message"]   . "\r\n";



    if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $header)) {
        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Thank you for contacting us.",
            "sendstatus" => 1
        );

        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Sorry, something is wrong.",
            "sendstatus" => 0
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
    }

}
```

And here is the html:

```
<form  id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="name" placeholder="First Name" value="" required="">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label  class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required="">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only">E-mail Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" value="" required="">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label  class="sr-only">Street</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="street" placeholder="Street" value="" required="">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control input-lg" rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-round btn-dark" >Send Email</button>
        </div>

    </div><!-- .row -->
</form>
```

I left the Email out on purpose,
Thank You for helping!

Comment: You dont have an `id=""` attributes on your `<input>` fields. So the javascript is not finding any of those fields to collect data from. `$('#contact-response');` specifically

Comment: Thank you, however only the street input won't go through on the email, any idea?

Comment: @RiggsFolly If so could you show me please, how one would add in such tags to make it work

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST); die();` to your `assets/php/contact.php` file. What does it display?

Comment: As in the email? @camelsWriteInCamelCase

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase Where should I putt the var_dump($_POST); die(); ?

Comment: At the beginning of the contact.php file.

Comment: It does not seem to work @camelsWriteInCamelCase

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase Could you give me an example of code on how to use those strings? thank you!